# Heat conduction equation (mixed problem)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How to solve this heat conduction equation
$u_t = u_{xx} -2u_x +x +2t,  0 \lt x \lt1, t \gt 0,
u \left( 0,t \right )=u \left(1,t \right) = t, u \left( x,0 \right) = e^x\sin \pi x$ ?
I tried to reduce this problem on equation with homogeneous boundary conditions, but I can't express Fourier coefficients.